# mysql_query Update of varchar doesn´t work with "-"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find out what the problem is since hours. I have a varchar(255).

works:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `servers` SET `url`='quicktest' WHERE `id`=63");
```

doesn't work:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `servers` SET `url`='quick-test' WHERE `id`=63");
```

What is wrong with the "-" chars that it doesn't work? I mean I can update it in phpmyadmin without problems and sometimes it even works via mysql_query. (1 of 20 cases)

About mysql_query I know that it is outdated but it is just updating internal stuff.

**Update #1**

I did not had this problem on an old debian 6 server but since it is on ubuntu 13.10 with maria db and php5-fpm I can´t use this script any more and I don´t get any errors.

**Update #2**

As it looks like it was related to either caching via the apache modules or the google pagespeed module.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: nope nothing, thats the why I don´t understand it.

Comment: add this to end of mysql_query()  `or die(mysql_error())` and check whether it prints any error

Comment: And please keep in mind that the mysql_* functions are deprecated, http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php : "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future"

Comment: @krishna I already have but it gives me no errors.

Comment: @VolkerK I know, but I don´t see any point on updating a risk free internal script just because of a newer php version.

Comment: ohh damn, it looks like that it was a caching issue after renaming the htaccess and disallowing google-pagespeed it works just fine. sorry for the trouble. what should I do with the question? delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but maybe it's worth to try:

```
$temp_url = mysql_real_escape_string('quick-test');
mysql_query("UPDATE `servers` SET `url`='".$temp_url."' WHERE `id`=63");
```

Comment: it is `quick-test` and not `quick_test`. Also it is not a solution you should post it as a comment.